# How do I make it so my code displays a cerrtain amount of lines (like it does) but backwards

Tags: java, string, for-loop, count, int

So when I enter 4, instead of say 4 bottles of beer etc, It will start with 100 and go to 96 and then stop (ending with the final line)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreeDotNine {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("How many Verses would you like to print:  ");
      String num = sc.nextLine();
      int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
      String s = " ";

      for (int x = num2; x > 0; x--) {
          System.out.println(x + " bottles of beer on the wall " + x + " bottles of beer");
          System.out.println("Take one down, pass it around, " + (x - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall.\n");
      }
      System.out.print("Go to the store, buy some more, ");
      System.out.println("99 bottles of beer on the wall.\n");

  }
}
```

Comment: start your loop at 100 and go down to 100 - num2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would try it like that:

```
for ( int x = 0; x <= num2; x++ ) {
  int y = 100 - x;

  System.out.println(y + " bottles of beer on the wall " + y + " bottles of beer");
  System.out.println("Take one down, pass it around, " + (y - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall.\n");
}
```

It's easier to understand if you define a second variable.

Now you have your output with
100
99
98
97
96

Comment: Or start `x = 100`, then `x--` the loop

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with the program. It works fine, Just check it again

```
How many Verses would you like to print:  4
4 bottles of beer on the wall 4 bottles of beer
Take one down, pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall.

3 bottles of beer on the wall 3 bottles of beer
Take one down, pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall 2 bottles of beer
Take one down, pass it around, 1 bottles of beer on the wall.

1 bottles of beer on the wall 1 bottles of beer
Take one down, pass it around, 0 bottles of beer on the wall.

Go to the store, buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.
```